# How to get a database field value from a WordPress table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm bumping my head against the wall here. I have searched here on SE and found several answers, but somehow they don't work for this scenario.

I have WordPress + MemberPress and I need to retrieve the current user's subscription status for subscription with ID = 48. MemberPress stores this value in their own table: mepr_subscriptions, field 'status'.

Now I need the string value of this status field.

I tried this:

```
$userID = get_current_user_id();
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "mepr_subscriptions";

$user = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT * FROM $table_name
    WHERE user_id = $userID
    AND product_id = 48"
);
```

A var_dump of $user shows this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#12026 (34) { ["id"]=> string(3) "115" ["user_id"]=> string(2) "58" ["product_id"]=> string(2) "48" ["coupon_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["subscr_id"]=> string(20) "mp-sub-6328ec8074400" ["price"]=> string(5) "37.00" ["total"]=> string(5) "37.00" ["tax_amount"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["tax_rate"]=> string(5) "0.000" ["tax_desc"]=> string(0) "" ["tax_compound"]=> string(1) "0" ["tax_shipping"]=> string(1) "1" ["tax_class"]=> string(8) "standard" ["gateway"]=> string(13) "upsell_stripe" ["response"]=> NULL ["period"]=> string(1) "1" ["period_type"]=> string(6) "months" ["limit_cycles"]=> string(1) "0" ["limit_cycles_num"]=> string(1) "2" ["limit_cycles_action"]=> string(6) "expire" ["limit_cycles_expires_after"]=> string(1) "1" ["limit_cycles_expires_type"]=> string(4) "days" ["prorated_trial"]=> string(1) "0" ["trial"]=> string(1) "0" ["trial_days"]=> string(1) "0" ["trial_amount"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["trial_tax_amount"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["trial_total"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["status"]=> string(9) "suspended" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2022-09-19 18:26:08" ["cc_last4"]=> string(0) "" ["cc_exp_month"]=> string(0) "" ["cc_exp_year"]=> string(0) "" ["token"]=> string(0) "" } }
```

I tried this:

```
$status = $user['status'];
```

Not working. $status remains empty.

I also tried this:

```
$json = json_encode($user);
$status = $json->status;
```

$json returns this:

```
[{"id":"115","user_id":"58","product_id":"48","coupon_id":"0","subscr_id":"mp-sub-6328ec8074400","price":"37.00","total":"37.00","tax_amount":"0.00","tax_rate":"0.000","tax_desc":"","tax_compound":"0","tax_shipping":"1","tax_class":"standard","gateway":"upsell_stripe","response":null,"period":"1","period_type":"months","limit_cycles":"0","limit_cycles_num":"2","limit_cycles_action":"expire","limit_cycles_expires_after":"1","limit_cycles_expires_type":"days","prorated_trial":"0","trial":"0","trial_days":"0","trial_amount":"0.00","trial_tax_amount":"0.00","trial_total":"0.00","status":"suspended","created_at":"2022-09-19 18:26:08","cc_last4":"","cc_exp_month":"","cc_exp_year":"","token":""}]
```

The variable $status remains empty.

And I tried this:

```
$json = json_encode($user[0]);
$status = $json->status;
```

$json returns this:

```
{"id":"115","user_id":"58","product_id":"48","coupon_id":"0","subscr_id":"mp-sub-6328ec8074400","price":"37.00","total":"37.00","tax_amount":"0.00","tax_rate":"0.000","tax_desc":"","tax_compound":"0","tax_shipping":"1","tax_class":"standard","gateway":"upsell_stripe","response":null,"period":"1","period_type":"months","limit_cycles":"0","limit_cycles_num":"2","limit_cycles_action":"expire","limit_cycles_expires_after":"1","limit_cycles_expires_type":"days","prorated_trial":"0","trial":"0","trial_days":"0","trial_amount":"0.00","trial_tax_amount":"0.00","trial_total":"0.00","status":"suspended","created_at":"2022-09-19 18:26:08","cc_last4":"","cc_exp_month":"","cc_exp_year":"","token":""}
```

The variable $status remains empty.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Memberpress and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic here and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first two cases, there's an array wrapping the object that you have to attend to first. e.g. this should work:

```
$status = $user[0]->status;
```

As a sidenote:

In the last case, `json_encode()` doesn't, as the name might suggest, turn data into an object with properties that you can access — it turns it into a JSON *string*. Not very useful here.

You can use `json_decode()` again to turn the string into an object — but of course why bother, since $user[0] is the object you want in the first place.